# How to change font size of axis titles in Apex charts?

Tags: axis, font-size, title, apexcharts

I have tried changing axis title font size using below code but it does not change font size.

```js
const options = {
  // ...
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function (value) {
        return "$" + value;
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Estimated Value',
      style:{
        fontSize: '28px'
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any other method to change the font size for axis titles in ApexCharts?

Answer (score 0):

### Use default `fontSize` property

I have implemented an example for creating the correct options. I have also created a dynamic variable called `fontSize` that tracks changes in its value (when it changes, I re-render the diagram). This way, you have the ability to change the font size to see how the setting works.

**After changing any setting, it is necessary to redraw the diagram**, which is why I put the rendering process into a separate function. Then, when a setting is changed, I call my rendering function again.

By default, ApexCharts only enables listening to the client window resize event, and in that case, it performs the same process.

##### Example

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed, watch, onMounted } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    /** Get Example Array **/
    const getRandomData = (length = 12) => Array.from(
      { length: length },
      () => Math.floor(Math.random() * length * 3)
    )  
    const data = ref(getRandomData())
    
    /** Get Fontsize **/
    const fontSize = ref(10)

    /** Render Chart **/
    const renderChart = () => {
      /** Clear #chart **/
      document.querySelector("#chart").innerHTML = ""
      /** Set new options **/
      const options = {
        chart: {
          type: 'line',
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Example Value',
          data: data.value,
        }],
        yaxis: {
          labels: {
            formatter: function (value) {
              return "$" + value;
            }           
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Estimated Value',
            style:{
              fontSize: `${fontSize.value}px`
            } 
          }
        }
      }
      /** Add new chart to #chart **/
      const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options)
      chart.render()
    }
    
    // Re-Render Chart when FontSize Changed
    watch(fontSize, renderChart)
    
    // Render Chart when Mounted
    onMounted(() => {
      renderChart()
    })
    
    return { fontSize, data, getRandomData }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
#chart, #originalChart {
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@latest"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button @click="fontSize--">-</button>
    <input v-model="fontSize" />
    <button @click="fontSize++">+</button>
  </div>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

### Alternative (with CSS class)

Use `apexcharts-text apexcharts-yaxis-title-text` definition on css.

```css
#chart .apexcharts-text.apexcharts-yaxis-title-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Mannipulate with JavaScript

```js
const chartTitle = chartContainer.querySelector(".apexcharts-text.apexcharts-yaxis-title-text")
chartTitle.style.fontSize = fontSize.value + "px"
```

##### Example #1

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed, watch, onMounted } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    /** Get Example Array **/
    const getRandomData = (length = 12) => Array.from(
      { length: length },
      () => Math.floor(Math.random() * length * 3)
    )  
    const data = ref(getRandomData())
    
    /** Get Fontsize **/
    const fontSize = ref(10)

    /** Render Chart **/
    const renderChart = () => {
      /** Clear #chart **/
      const chartContainer = document.querySelector("#chart")
      chartContainer.innerHTML = ""
      /** Set new options **/
      const options = {
        chart: {
          type: 'line',
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Example Value',
          data: data.value,
        }],
        yaxis: {
          labels: {
            formatter: function (value) {
              return "$" + value;
            }           
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Estimated Value',
          }
        }
      }
      /** Add new chart to #chart **/
      const chart = new ApexCharts(chartContainer, options)
      chart.render()
      
      /** Set title's fontSize **/
      const chartTitle = chartContainer.querySelector(".apexcharts-text.apexcharts-yaxis-title-text")
      chartTitle.style.fontSize = fontSize.value + "px"
    }
    
    // Re-Render Chart when FontSize Changed
    watch(fontSize, renderChart)
    
    // Render Chart when Mounted
    onMounted(() => {
      renderChart()
    })
    
    return { fontSize, data, getRandomData }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
#chart, #originalChart {
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 300px;
}

#chart .apexcharts-text.apexcharts-yaxis-title-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@latest"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button @click="fontSize--">-</button>
    <input v-model="fontSize" />
    <button @click="fontSize++">+</button>
  </div>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

##### Example #2

With `Object.assign()`

```js
const chartStyle = computed(() => ({
  fontSize: `${fontSize.value}px`
}))

const chartTitle = chartContainer.querySelector(".apexcharts-text.apexcharts-yaxis-title-text")
Object.assign(chartTitle.style, chartStyle.value)
```

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed, watch, onMounted } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    /** Get Example Array **/
    const getRandomData = (length = 12) => Array.from(
      { length: length },
      () => Math.floor(Math.random() * length * 3)
    )  
    const data = ref(getRandomData())
    
    /** Get Fontsize **/
    const fontSize = ref(10)
    /** Get Title's style **/
    const chartStyle = computed(() => ({
      fontSize: `${fontSize.value}px`
    }))

    /** Render Chart **/
    const renderChart = () => {
      /** Clear #chart **/
      const chartContainer = document.querySelector("#chart")
      chartContainer.innerHTML = ""
      /** Set new options **/
      const options = {
        chart: {
          type: 'line',
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Example Value',
          data: data.value,
        }],
        yaxis: {
          labels: {
            formatter: function (value) {
              return "$" + value;
            }           
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Estimated Value',
          }
        }
      }
      /** Add new chart to #chart **/
      const chart = new ApexCharts(chartContainer, options)
      chart.render()
      
      /** Set title's fontSize **/
      const chartTitle = chartContainer.querySelector(".apexcharts-text.apexcharts-yaxis-title-text")
      Object.assign(chartTitle.style, chartStyle.value)
    }
    
    // Re-Render Chart when FontSize Changed
    watch(fontSize, renderChart)
    
    // Render Chart when Mounted
    onMounted(() => {
      renderChart()
    })
    
    return { fontSize, data, getRandomData }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
#chart, #originalChart {
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 300px;
}

#chart .apexcharts-text.apexcharts-yaxis-title-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@latest"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button @click="fontSize--">-</button>
    <input v-model="fontSize" />
    <button @click="fontSize++">+</button>
  </div>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any simple method (like adding a property fontSize in style) ?

Comment: If you manipulate the font size using CSS, it works, but in that case, the ApexCharts code cannot calculate the title position correctly. Therefore, you need to take care of it yourself. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Always try to use the preferred default settings recommended by the package!

Comment: @Hemanth, Did you manage to solve the issue with the addition?

Comment: no it did not work

Comment: @Hemanth My example works, right? Have you tried testing just this one function in an empty environment to ensure its functionality without any other influencing factors?